# Error in read.table(), no lines available in input

Tags: r, read.csv

I'm trying to read the csv for brain_counts found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aayush9753/singlecell-rnaseq-data-from-mouse-brain?select=brain_counts.csv

```
rna <- read.csv("brain_counts.csv")
```

^ that is my code. I get the error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :
> no lines available in input

How can I fix this? I know similar a similar question has been asked but this dataset is found on Kaggle and not Github.

Comment: The error suggests that the downloaded file is empty. Did you inspect its contents or check its size before trying to read into R? By the way, Kaggle datasets can often be found elsewhere _e.g._ Github and people prefer to download from locations that don't require an account.

Comment: @neilfws The size is fairly large. 168,500 KB and contains 10,000 columns with 3401 unique genes/observations

Comment: are those values what you expect, or what you know exists in the file on your machine?